# Running into OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error when trying to have program restart itself

Tags: python

I'm trying to have a file of mine restart itself to update the page that it is gathering information from but I am getting an error with the error code OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error

My code is here

```
import os
import sys
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request

sauce = urllib.request.urlopen('https://robinhood.com/crypto/DOGE')
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'lxml')


def trackDoge():
    for span in soup.find_all('div', class_='QzVHcLdwl2CEuEMpTUFaj'):
        print(span.text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    trackDoge()
    os.execv(r'C:/Users/Brand/PycharmProjects/DogeSoup/main.py', sys.argv)
```

If anyone can help pinpoint how to fix this error I would appreciate it.

Comment: Have you tried `os.execv(sys.argv[0], sys.argv)`?

Comment: Put your code into a function and call it in a loop.

Comment: I just attempted os.execv(sys.argv[0], sys.argv) and it didnt work for me, just gave me the same error

Comment: I also just tried making it into a function and it gave me the same error after 1 output